# in sublime how to abort previous build automatically when building again

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I know that there is key mapping to cancel build.
But I want automatically when I press Ctrl+B, that it will abort the previous built.

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it possible, that the "cancel" build will do some works. And not just terminate the program (for example, send the kill signal, and let the NodeJS program time to close all the sockets...)

For example:

```
http.createServer().listen(80)
```

It is works in the first time I press Ctrl+B. but in the second time, I always get **cannot bind to port 80...**

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677)? It would allow you to run Cancel Build and then Build.

Comment: Searching for simpler solution. I believe there is a paramater to the build_system to say that it will run only one instance at a time

Comment: After Building the project, does a second Build cause the server to shutdown eventually? Or does the server continue to run normally after the second build?

Comment: Is the target platform Windows or Linux? (Or both even)

Answer (score 2):

- Make your app write a pid file.

  Either in the build script where the service is spawned write your own pid.
  Or by the service itself, Things like Apache and NGinx should write their own somewhere. If this is your app you might consider writing your own pid file. Usual locations to my knowledge are
  `/var/run` for system processes, starting a webservice might qualify,
  or `~/.appname`, that's a hidden file named after yoru app in your
  home directory.

  In the WindowsNT Environment [getting your pid may be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2328776/1695680), and [killing a process by pid <sup>⇗</sup>](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb491009.aspx) may also be tricky.
- On build, before spawning your app, kill the previous build process(es) by id, specified in the pidfile.

### Protype code:

Verbose and commented: https://gist.github.com/thorsummoner/f1fc7acf94cf9696ef75

I can't bring myself to boil it down anymore and its ~70 lines of function-oriented code and meant to be modified for specific use.

Its also not tested as I don't have a particularly good use case for this.

Comment: I will look into prototyping a way to do this in sublime native tonight, though I can't give any assurance that it will work in Windows

Comment: @Amina Can you provide an example of your current .sublime-build file? or build system configuration?